# Using get(); in a Laravel Command

Tags: php, laravel

As of yesterday, I seem to be having issues returning objects in commands in Laravel. I have the following code:

```
$users = app(User::class)
    ->get();
```

When I dump the variable `$users`, I get the following output ***Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection*** and the command fails to finish.

[image]

If I instead run the following:

```
$users = app(User::class)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

That outputs an array of users no problem.

I'm not sure if this is a Laravel issue, I feel like when I installed a new package via composer yesterday, I saw a minor update to Laravel but I'm not 100% sure.

Can anyone else replicate this?

Comment: Why are you not using `User::all()->toArray()`? What is the need for the `app()` helper?

Comment: It's not an issue, it's the way it's supposed to work. `get()` on an eloquent query always returns a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-collections) of objects.

Comment: I've updated my wording slightly. When I run it with get(), it doesn't actually return a collection of objects, it just returns "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection" in terminal and then fails to stop.

Comment: By "fails to stop", do you mean it just keeps printing out data? If you have a lot of users with relationships, it might be printing out everything, which can get overwhelming. `toArray()` seems to be working fine (a Collection method to convert the class to an array of arrays), so after the get you should be able to iterate through the users as you need to.

Comment: Nope, it prints out no data other than "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection". It looks like it's getting stuck but I'm not sure how to debug it further

Comment: Can you do `foreach($users as $user) var_dump($user);` or `echo $users->count();`?

Comment: Echoing the count works along with foreaching and var_dumping. If I dump $users without foreaching, then I get the "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection" text

Comment: Just use what @thisiskelvin has mentioned. that's one-liner.
$users = User::all()->toArray();

Comment: They may have changed the way it shows the assignment, then, to reduce output to the screen, but everything will still work as normal.

Comment: Just seems a bit odd that it only does this in commands, I've just pasted the exact same query into a controller and it works fine

Comment: So it looks like Laravel did update to 5.8.21. I have an application running 5.8 and that seems to handle this fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am always using

```
use App/User; //or location of your model

$users = User::get();
```

Also try:

```
Use DB;

$users = DB::table('users')->get();
```